# Unable to login or signin with Q-municate v1.1.4

Tags: quickblox, quickblox-android, q-municate

I have downloaded old source code Q-municate v1.1.4 before and it works until today it doesn't work anymore but v2.6.1 it works fine.

Q-municate v1.1.4 no longer support anymore? Do I need to use v2.0+ instead?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a critical issue on Shared server (https://admin.quickblox.com).

Quickblox technical operations team is currently working on it
You can see status on the issue and future updates here: http://quickblox.com/blog/shared-instance-chat-performance-degradation/

and the overall server status here: https://status.quickblox.com/instance/prod

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with the QuickBlox web service. My Android and JS-Apps  can’t get connected to https://chat.quickblox.com:5291.  Have the same problem with the [sample apps form QuickBlox](https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android#Prepare_your_application_for_Android_SDK).